# What spider is this?

Tags: united-states, bugs, bug-identification, spider

I’m in the northern Dallas Fort Worth area. The spider was bigger than a silver dollar, it was massive. I could see its eyes down the trail on the pavement. It wasn’t an egg sack on its back that’s its actual body. Thought wolf spider at first but not sure, anyone???

[image]

Comment: As you mentioned a dollar, I assume you are US based. For the few of us that don't live in the USA, could you please expand on the "northern DFW area".

Comment: @Darren - DFW is the Dallas-Fort Worth area, and the large airport that many people fly through.

Comment: @JonCuster I just assumed that this is correct and suggested an edit.

Comment: Welcome to the site - for those of us who aren't from the USA, how big is a silver dollar? Is that measurement body length or across the leg span?

Comment: While we can look up the size of a silver dollar (about 26mm or just over an inch) we still don't know what that applies to. As bob1 says, body or legs? That makes a big difference, so with no further info having appeared I'm voting to close